# How to Flutter App run continuously fetch data after every 10 sec in background when app is closed/terminated or screen off

Tags: flutter, dart, geolocation, location, background-process

How to Flutter App run continuously in the background when the app is closed/terminated. I have to fetch the location continuously when the app is terminated/closed or the screen is locked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try work manager

https://pub.dev/packages/workmanager

Create a root level method and use that method to create a background process.

```
void callbackDispatcher() {
  Workmanager().executeTask((task, inputData) {
    print("Native called background task: $backgroundTask"); //simpleTask will be emitted here.
    return Future.value(true);
  });
}

void main() {
  Workmanager().initialize(
    callbackDispatcher, // The top level function, aka callbackDispatcher
    isInDebugMode: true // If enabled it will post a notification whenever the task is running. Handy for debugging tasks
  );
  Workmanager().registerOneOffTask("task-identifier", "simpleTask");
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

Comment: It's useful to know that they run in a different isolate (thread) so there's no memory sharing with the main thread we are used to work with.

Comment: but i want to fetch data continuously after every 10 sec but in workmanger  minimum duration is 15 min. so can youi suggest me another example.

Comment: 10 seconds is too short a period. You can probably add a timer in the method and call the api.

Comment: in desktop its not working can you suggest for desktop